# Necessary and/or sufficient conditions for LR coefficients of Schubert polynomials to be zero

Tags: co.combinatorics, schubert-calculus, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

There is a simple condition for determining whether LR coefficients for Schur polynomials are $0$, without invoking the Littlewood-Richardson rule. Is there anything similar, possibly weaker, for Schubert polynomials? I'm looking for necessary and/or sufficient conditions for the coefficients to be zero/nonzero.

I was able to find a nontrivial necessary condition for them to be nonzero myself that also works for double Schubert polynomials, but it's definitely not sufficient.

To give an idea of what I'm looking for, let me flesh out my necessary condition for it to be nonzero. For a permutation $u$, define
$$c_i(u)=\{j>i\mid u(i)>u(j)\}$$
We say that $u$ is dominant if $c_i(u)\geq c_{i+1}(u)$ for all $i$. We note that $u$ is dominant if and only if $u^{-1}$ is dominant. For each $u$, we define a dominant permutation $\mu(u)$ recursively by declaring that if $u$ is dominant then $\mu(u)=u$, and if $u$ is not dominant, let $i$ be the maximal index such that $c_i(u^{-1})<c_{i+1}(u^{-1})$, and define
$$\mu(u)=\mu(s_iu)$$

Consider the coefficient
$$c_{u,v}^w$$
Define $\mu(u,v)$ to be the permutation that such that
$$c_i(\mu(u,v))=c_i(\mu(u))+c_i(\mu(v))$$
for all $i$. Then $c_{u,v}^w=0$ unless
$$\ell(\mu(u,v)w^{-1})=\ell(\mu(u,v))-\ell(w)$$

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0501076 for a polynomial time algorithm for determining whether a Littlewood-Richardson coefficient is 0.